# Bootstrap 3 Apply different CSS on Mobile and computer

Tags: css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a bootstrap 3, have an `div` element with `class` `outer` and want to apply different css on mobile and computer.

For example, this is my css codes:

```
/* for computer */
div.outer {
     height: calc(100vh - 80px);
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     min-height: 500px
}


/* for mobile */
div.outer  {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}
```

How do I implement it? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: you dont want to use media query?

Comment: Thanks for all answers which are working for me. Sorry I cannot accept all answers, but only pick the first answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Use media query for mobile devices. below is template, dont forgot to add mobile meta tag.
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 570px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
     //your css for mobile is here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using media queries for this one.
To change the `div.outer` class when in mobile use the code below.

```
/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
  div.outer  {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
 }
}
```

More media queries [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries)

Answer (score 1):

For mobile you have tp define width of the device in '@media' queries.

767px is a standard width of screen for mobile and tablets. So you can use like this

```
@media all and (max-width:768px){
    // your css for mobile
}
```

> This css will apply only when you device width will be 768px or less